# Vue js: Is it posible to initialize data through a method?

Tags: methods, vuejs2, initialization

Basically I want to initialize my **vValidNombre** field on my form by comparing two values, so It would be nice to use a method, something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var avatar = new Vue({
    el: '#validaciones',
    data: {
      vNombre: $('input[name=nombre]').val(),
      vValidNombre: validar(),
    },
    methods: {
      validar: function(){
        if ('true' == 'true') {
          return = true;
        }
        else {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
  })
</script>
```

This code doesn't work, but is it possible to do something like that?

EDIT: I'm using Vue 2

Comment: Interestingly enough, this works perfectly in a component, just not in a view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. When it is initialised, `vValidNombre` would be undefined. However, you can do something like this with the `ready` method:

```
var avatar = new Vue({
    el: '#validaciones',
    data: {
        vNombre: $('input[name=nombre]').val(),
        vValidNombre: null,
    },

    ready: function() {
        this.vValidNombre = this.validar();
    }

    methods: {
      validar: function(){
          // do something here
          // and return it
      },

      bindDom: function() {

      } 
    },

})
```

Comment: This solution works but since I'm using Vue 2 the method is called mount instead of ready. Why bindDom() though?

Comment: I usually use bindDom, well, to literally bind my DOM elements. You can have much more control over the logic then.